# Why this query with in clause returns no error?

Tags: sql

I've tried this on diverse db's on sqlfiddle.com

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_col1 int NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE b (
  b_col1 int NOT NULL
); 

select * from a where a_col1 in (select a_col1 from b);
```

Is not evident the error in "select a_col1 from b" ?
Populating table a it returns all rows from table a at least in MySQL.

Comment: Because it's referring to the outer table. You've turned it into a correlated subquery. You're getting all rows back (where a_col1 isnt null) because the value is always equal to itself.

Answer (score 4):

No error at all in the compiler, only in the person writing the code.  You think the code says:

```
where a.a_col1 in (select b.a_col1 from b);
```

But that is not how SQL scoping rules work.  `a_col1` isn't found in `b`, so SQL assumes this is a *correlated* subquery and interprets it as:

```
where a.a_col1 in (select a.a_col1 from b);
```

No mystery.  Just a bad habit.  *Always* qualify the column references in your queries.